# UWP buttons not redrawing correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, button, uwp

So I was testing out my UWP app and I noticed something weird with my buttons and conditional formatting.

The app looks at the day and determines which buttons to show based on that day.

If it is not the day in question, it shows this:
[image]

But if I were to go back and changed the day to the appropriate day that meets the condition, it shows this:

[image]

And if I had chosen the correct conditional day before ever going to the page in question, I get the correct formatting:
[image]

Any ideas?

XAML Snippet:

```
        <Button Name="CHWPButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"
                Margin="50,10,45,10"
                Content="CHWP"
                Click="CHWPButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU1A2B7AButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="CHWPButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="CHWPButton"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 1A/2B/7A"
                Click="AHU1A2B7AButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="CHWPButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="AHU1A2B7AButton"
                FontSize="10"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 2B/3C/4D/9C/10D"
                Click="AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU4D5E6RButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="CHWPButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 4D/5E/6R"
                Click="AHU4D5E6RButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHURoom3020Button"
                RelativePanel.Below="CHWPButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"                    
                Margin="50,10,45,10"
                Content="Room 3020"
                Click="AHURoom3020Button_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU22D23E24RButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="AHURoom3020Button"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="AHURoom3020Button"
                FontSize="12"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"                    
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 22D/23E/24R"
                Click="AHU22D23E24RButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU19A20B21CButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="AHU22D23E24RButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="AHURoom3020Button"
                FontSize="12"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"                    
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 19A/20B/21C"
                Click="AHU19A20B21CButton_Click">
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AHU10D11E12RButton"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="AHU19A20B21CButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="AHURoom3020Button"
                FontSize="12"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Width="135"
                Height="50"
                Style="{StaticResource EQButton}"                    
                Margin="0,0,45,0"
                Content="AHU 10D/11E/12R"
                Click="AHU10D_11E_12RButton_Click">
        </Button>
```

And the C# file potion:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DC6Rounds.Pages;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace DC6Rounds
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void IconsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GeneralListBoxItem.IsSelected)
            {
                FrameContent.Navigate(typeof(GeneralPage));
                Title.Text = "General";
                SignInButtonStatus();
                GeneralPageButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                BMSButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                WeeklyPeakReadingsButtonStatus();
                ColdWeatherButtonStatus();
            }
            else if (MechanicalPenthouseListBoxItem.IsSelected)
            {
                if (App.Day == "Tue")
                {
                    FrameContent.Navigate(typeof(AHU1A2B7APage));
                    Title.Text = "AHU 1A/2B/7A";
                }
                else
                {
                    FrameContent.Navigate(typeof(CHWPPage));
                    Title.Text = "CHWP";
                }
                MechanicalPenthouseButtons();
            }
        }

        public void HideButtons()
        {
            //Main Buttons
            SubmitButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            SignInButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            FileButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            //Mechanical Penthouse Buttons
            AHU1A2B7AButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 1
            AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 2
            AHU4D5E6RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 3
            MainPenthouseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 4
            CHWPButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 5
            AHU13A14B15CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 6
            AHU15C16D17E21C22DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 7
            AHU17E18R24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 8
            AHURoom3020Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 9
            AHU22D23E24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 10
            AHU19A20B21CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Button 11
            AHU10D11E12RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 12
            AHU7A8B9CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Button 13
        }

        public void MechanicalPenthouseButtons()
        {
            if(App.Day == "Tue")
            {
                SignInButtonStatus();
                AHU1A2B7AButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 1
                AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 2
                AHU4D5E6RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 3
                MainPenthouseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 4
                CHWPButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 5
                AHU13A14B15CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 6
                AHU15C16D17E21C22DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 7
                AHU17E18R24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 8
                AHURoom3020Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 9
                AHU22D23E24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 10
                AHU19A20B21CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 11
                AHU10D11E12RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 12
                AHU7A8B9CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 13
            }
            else
            {
                SignInButtonStatus();
                CHWPButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 5
                CHWPButton.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 0, 0);
                AHURoom3020Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 9
                AHURoom3020Button.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        public void SignInButtonStatus()
        {
            if (SignInButton.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                HideButtons();
                SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                HideButtons();
                SignInButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            SaveNotesButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain what is the exact problem here? do you want your formatiing to be correct? what is you want to achieve but not able to? Also most important part of the question is the code, please post both the relevant xaml and backend c# conditional code.

Comment: We will need to see the XAML you are using

Comment: OK.  Added the code as requested.  Basically wondering why the 2nd picture does not look like the 3rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I did it to myself.  I originally had set up these two buttons in the middle of the page, so I had modified the margin of them, but I used different numbers.

```
        public void MechanicalPenthouseButtons()
        {
            if(App.Day == "Tue")
            {
                SignInButtonStatus();
                AHU1A2B7AButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 1
                AHU2B3C4D9C10DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 2
                AHU4D5E6RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 3
                MainPenthouseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 4
                CHWPButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 5
                AHU13A14B15CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 6
                AHU15C16D17E21C22DButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 7
                AHU17E18R24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 8
                AHURoom3020Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 9
                AHU22D23E24RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 10
                AHU19A20B21CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Button 11
                AHU10D11E12RButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 12
                AHU7A8B9CButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 13
            }
            else
            {
                SignInButtonStatus();
                CHWPButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 5
                CHWPButton.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 45, 10); // Was (50,10,0,0)
                AHURoom3020Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Button 9
                AHURoom3020Button.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 45, 10); // Was (50,10,0,0)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Actually, deleted the .Margin lines altogether.